# Listen to task canceled event in the browser

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, twilio, twilio-taskrouter

I am using Twilio Taskrouter for making reservations for a video call. What I want is to notify the user that all workers are currently busy, with a message displayed for the user on the browser. So I wanted to know how can one catch the `task.canceled` event in the browser so that I can notify the user about the task getting canceled due to the task timeout. I have seen the JS SDK for Twilio but I only saw events for Workers, Workspace and Task Queues and couldn't find any such events for Tasks, so is there anyway I can listen to the task's events on the browser side?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a way to get the assignment status of the task, more details can be found here: [TaskRouter Task Resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/api/task#task-attributes). On this page look for `assignmentStatus` resource property. The current status of the Task's assignment. Can be: **pending**, **reserved**, **assigned**, **canceled**, **wrapping**, or **completed**

let me know what you think.